# Operating a latching 24V DC valve with non-reversible current direction signal

Tags: valves, flow-control

Most 24V DC latching valves require a reversal of the current flow direction to be able to switch between open/close states. However, is there a way to operate them with a signal that can only go 0V to +24V and is impossible to reverse?

Perhaps there are latching valves that can operate based on rising edge?

Comment: 1. Is there a 24 V supply available at the valve? 2. "*Perhaps there are latching valves that can operate based on rising edge?*" That would be a toggle operation but why not just use a regular spring-return type if you have the option to replace the valve?

Comment: Yes...Use an H-Bridge.  They are generally used for DC motors to swap direction.  The bridge handles the reversal for you and if wired appropriately, the valve will be none the wiser.

Comment: Can the valve be actuated continuously? If so, you can use a DPDT relay to do this. If not, 2 states isn't enough to command open/closed AND how long to actuate for. You'd need some additional logic at the valve like a 555 or a microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a latching solenoid, you want a dual coil solenoid valve. There are two kinds of dual coil solenoids. The more common is a two-way valve. Each coil operates one of the two ways conventionally, ie power on to activate, power off to return. You want the second kind of dual solenoid. It is a one-way with two coils. The first coil is the pull coil and the second coil is the hold coil. It is almost the same as the latching solenoid except it still needs a tiny bit of power to the hold coil to stay latched. When you break the hold coil, it drops out.